# How to handle CSV files with multiple comma separated values in the same column

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk

My CSV file format. Notice that the 6th row has multiple comma separated values for the same column.

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p,q,r
s,t,u,v,w,x
y,z,ab,bc,cd,de
"a,b,c",d,e,f,g,"h,i,j"
```

Now, If I fire `awk -F, '{print $1}'`, then for the 6th row, I get incorrect results.

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1}' test.csv
a
g
m
s
y
"a
```

How can I handle these multiple comma separated values for the same column with awk or with any other utility (sed, cut etc)?

Comment: Install and use ```csvtool```:  ```csvtool col 1 test.csv```. There is already an existing answer for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU-[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) with a regex that captures between `""`'s:

```
➜  /tmp cat test.csv
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p,q,r
s,t,u,v,w,x
y,z,ab,bc,cd,de
"a,b,c",d,e,f,g,"h,i,j"
➜  /tmp
➜  /tmp
➜  /tmp awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; } { print $1 }' test.csv
a
g
m
s
y
"a,b,c"
➜  /tmp
```

---

The `FPAT` value is a regex that describes the content of each field (col).

So in your CSV example, the 'content of each field' is any value that is (optionally) wrapped in quotes (`""`).

---

For more information, refer to the gawk manual:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html

Comment: I've added some explanation, for more info, please check the official manual with the provided link.